# How to get date difference in SQL?

Tags: sql

The original Table is like this :-

```
id  user_id item    created_at  revenue
1   109     milk    2020-03-03  123
2   139     biscuit 2020-03-18  421
3   120     milk    2020-03-18  176
4   108     banana  2020-03-18  862
5   130     milk    2020-03-28  333
6   103     bread   2020-03-29  862
7   122    banana   2020-03-07  952
```

Then I write a code like below:-

```
select 
    user_id,
    min(created_at) as first_date,
    max(created_at) as new_date
from amazon_transactions
group by user_id;
```

result:-

```
user_id first_date  new_date
117    2020-03-10   2020-03-22
113    2020-03-21   2020-03-21
125    2020-03-13   2020-03-13
120    2020-03-06   2020-03-27
107    2020-03-01   2020-03-01
128    2020-03-04   2020-03-28
142    2020-03-09   2020-03-09
110    2020-03-13   2020-03-27
145    2020-03-07   2020-03-07
```

How do I get date difference between the column of first_date & new_date?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Sorry not sure..I'm doing exercise at here..https://platform.stratascratch.com/

Comment: Probably postgreSQL then. https://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff

Comment: `select version();` will give Postgresql version, if Postrgresql.

Comment: This code works -->> 
DATEDIFF(max(created_at), min(created_at)) as days_difference ..
The difference is I took out the days,however I have one more condition to be fulfilled which is the days_difference must be more than 7 days..but when I add :_
(where days_difference > 7) error came out say 'days_difference' does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DATEDIFF(interval, date1, date2)` function in sql.

```
select 
    user_id,
    min(created_at) as first_date,
    max(created_at) as new_date,
    DATEDIFF(day, min(created_at), max(created_at)) as days_difference
from amazon_transactions
group by user_id;
```

Comment: I got this error:
(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "day" does not exist
LINE 5:     DATEDIFF(day, max(created_at), min(created_at)) as days_...
                     ^

[SQL: select 
    user_id,
    min(created_at) as first_date,
    max(created_at) as new_date,
    DATEDIFF(day, max(created_at), min(created_at)) as days_difference
from amazon_transactions
group by user_id;]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Comment: An error may have been returned because you probably used double quotes for string text. Please use single quotes for string text. Double quotes are for names of tables or fields.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified...

Comment: After I change your code to this,then I able to see the days_difference :-              
select 
    user_id,
    min(created_at) as first_date,
    max(created_at) as new_date,
    DATEDIFF(max(created_at), min(created_at)) as days_difference
from amazon_transactions
group by user_id;